# Why should I use JLabel instead of Image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I always see people loading an image into a [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html). Are there any advantages of using JLabel over [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)?

And when I should use Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any advantages of using JLabel over Image?

If all you want to do is display an image at its actual size then use a JLabel so you don't reinvent the wheel.

> And when I should use Image?

If you want to customize the painting of the image. Maybe to do dynamic scaling, tiling, rotations etc.

Comment: I am designing a game which calls repaint() in a game loop. However, the [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) variable given in "paintComponent()" does not support drawing a JLabel. Does it mean it is better to use Image in my case? Or I should not use "repaint()"?

Comment: Probably better to paint the image directly in the paintComponent() method. You would keep an ArrayList of all the objects that need to be painted and then just iterate through the List.

Answer (score 0):

An `Image` is not a Swing component but a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon` is. So when you want to place your `Image` to a regular Swing container you have to use a `JLabel`. But there are other ways to decorate an `Image` to become a `Component`,  `JXImagePanel` from the SwingX project is an example.